# Error message and empty list of build definitions in VS2012 after adding favorites

Tags: visual-studio, build, tfs, visual-studio-2012

We have a bunch of build definitions available through TFS, and these were visible under *Team Explorer - Builds* in VS until a few minutes ago, when I tried to add a couple of them to "Favourites".

All I did was right click a build definition, and select "Add to favorites", then repeat the process for another build definition:

[image]

The result however, is a now empty list of build definitions - I can't seem to find any of them again. Furthermore, I get the following error message:

**An item with the same key has already been added.**

Any ideas how to fix this? Anyone know where the list of "favorites" is stored? (My reasoning is that if I can find and empty that list, then perhaps this issue would disapear?)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Favourites are stored in metadata on the user or group.  You'll need to write an app to clear them.

http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2012/10/18/tfs-api-add-favorites-programmatically.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response, interesting! Anyway, the problem just seemed to solve itself - I logged in today (one day after posting the above question), and everything works fine. Maybe logging out and back in was enough to reload my profile, and clear it up? Anyway, you get the accepted answer for your link. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue today.  I was able to resolve it with the following steps.

- Close Visual Studio
- Open C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\FavoritesStore
- Move the xml file from that folder to some other location
- Start Visual Studio, open team explorer and navigate to Builds
- At this point, the Builds pane opened without the error and "My Favorite Build Definitions" was empty
- Moved the xml file back to its original location
- Refresh the builds pane.

After refreshing, my favorite build definitions were back!

Answer (score 1):

You may try (this helped to me with the same issue) to delete all the files in the following folder and restart VS2012 ([Source](http://henrywrites.wordpress.com/2012/11/19/tfs-vs2012-an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-added/comment-page-1/#comment-12)):
**C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache**

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurred for me today when I had a mystery dialog open and it was blocking user input.  I could not locate it or bring focus to it. I had to force a shutdown of VS, and after restarting my favorites were corrupt.

I found you can delete the cache for the favorites directly and restart the IDE.  As soon as it launches you will see that VS will recreate the folder, and as soon as you add your first favorite a new favorites file will be created at that location.
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\FavoritesStore

Writing an application or clearing the adjacent Cache folder are not necessary.